# listview OnItemCommand dosen't fire up

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, button

when i press either linkbutton in the listviews it dosen't fire up at all

```
<div>
   <%
      String[] d1 = { "1", "2", "3" };
      String[] d2 = { "4", "5", "6", "7" };
      ListView1.DataSource = d1;
      ListView1.DataBind();
      ListView2.DataSource = d2;
      ListView2.DataBind();
   %>
   <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" OnItemCommand="lv_command">
      <LayoutTemplate>
          <ul>
              <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
          </ul>
      </LayoutTemplate>
      <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
      </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:ListView>
   <asp:ListView ID="ListView2" runat="server" OnItemCommand="lv_command">
      <LayoutTemplate>
          <ul>
              <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
          </ul>
      </LayoutTemplate>
      <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
      </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:ListView>
</div>

protected void lv_command(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
  int i = 0;
}
```

Comment: This works for me. I'm assuming your event handler code is in the code-behind. Is your ListView inside an UpdatePanel?

Comment: could you give me an example of an event handler code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the CommandName property of each of the LinkButtons, for instance:

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName="MyCommand">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
```

Thus when the ItemCommand event is raised you can detect whether it is fired from a link button as follows:

```
     protected void lv_command(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
  if(e.CommandName == "MyCommand")
  {
    //do something
  }
}
```

Also it is more performance-wise to bind the listview on initial load only and bind it again from certain event handlers when needed:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(!Page.IsPostBack)
   {
    String[] d1 = { "1", "2", "3" };
    String[] d2 = { "4", "5", "6", "7" };
    ListView1.DataSource = d1;
    ListView1.DataBind();
    ListView2.DataSource = d2;
    ListView2.DataBind();
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi Dick..can you help me..How to trigger event button click on button **LinkButton1**  by the _telerik:RadComboBox_ On **OnSelectedIndexChanged** event Or **OnClientSelectedIndexChanged** event ? can you give me example ?

Answer (score 0):

Move the logic that performs data binding into the code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String[] d1 = { "1", "2", "3" };
    String[] d2 = { "4", "5", "6", "7" };
    ListView1.DataSource = d1;
    ListView1.DataBind();
    ListView2.DataSource = d2;
    ListView2.DataBind();
}

protected void lv_command(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
  int i = 0;
}
```